# OpenKm using java

Tags: java, spring-boot, openkm

can anyone tell me how to connect to openkm from a client system to the server using java?
I am working on a project where there is a need to connect to openkm and store the file there in the server.
I had seen some examples but not able to find the right solution from it.

This link https://docs.openkm.com/kcenter/view/okm-6.4/okmdocument.html i had seen but the OKMDocument is not able to find.

can anyone provide me the solution?